# Modify the function `Simplify`

Tags: functions, simplifying-expressions

When I use `Simplify` with equations, the function simplifies both sides of the equation, for example:

```
In[1108]:= Simplify[a + b == b + c + d]

Out[1108]= a == c + d
```

When I use `Simplify` with rules, the function simplifies side by side, for example:

```
In[1109]:= Simplify[a + b -> b + c + d]

Out[1109]= a + b -> b + c + d
```

How can I set a new function (maybe calls `SideSimplify`) that simplifies side by side, both equations and rules?

Comment: Just `Map` the `Simplify` onto the equation or rule: `Simplify /@ a + b == b + c + d` or `Simplify /@ a + b -> b + c + d`

Answer (score 1):

Starting in M11.3 you can use one of the `*Sides` functions to manipulate equations. For your example you could use the general [`ApplySides`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ApplySides) function:

```
ApplySides[Simplify, a + b == b + c + d]
```

> a + b == b + c + d